# .addClass/.removeClass CSS Animations not working

Tags: html, jquery, css

I've been trying to use Jquery Animate and CSS however I cannot seem to get it to work;

```
  $(function() {
    var navShrink = $("#nav-anim");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
      var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scroll >= 500) {
        navShrink.removeClass("navigation").addClass("nav-shrink");
      } else {
        navShrink.removeClass("nav-shrink").addClass("navigation");
      }
    });
  });
```

css;

```
#nav-anim {
  transition: height 1s ease; 
}

.navigation {
  height: 12.5vh;
}

.nav-shrink {
  height: 7!important;
}
```

html but ive left out all my content

```
<div id="nav-anim" class="row navigation fixed-top no-gutters">

</div>
```

This code works, it shrinks the height of my navigation bar after 500px. However it has no transition. I just want to ease the height change. Each class it is changing to has a different "height" property set.

Wondering if there's a way to do this without jquery ui.

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `!important` rule so you don't override styles. This should be best practice.

**Update:** Added the snippet without the use of jQuery.

```js
const navShrink = document.querySelector('.navigation__container');
document.onscroll = shrinkNavigation => window.pageYOffset >= 500 ? navShrink.classList.add('nav-shrink') : navShrink.classList.remove('nav-shrink');
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.section {
  height: 3000px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.navigation__container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: bisque;
  height: 12.5vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

.nav-shrink {
  height: 7vh;
}

.menu {
  list-style: none;
}

.nav-shrink.menu__item--anchor {
  color: white;
}

.menu {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <nav class="navigation__container">
    <ul class="menu">
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a class="menu__item--anchor" href="#">link 1</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice non jQuery solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following lines to your CSS:

```
.navigation,
.nav-shrink {
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.4s;
    -moz-transition: height 0.4s;
    -o-transition: height  0.4s;
    -ms-transition: height  0.4s;
    transition: height  0.4s;
}
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Notes:
1. you don't need to remove a class, just add height in `#nav-anim` and toggle the class `nav-shrink` with the new height.
2. remove unessecary `!important`, as new height will be applied because the new class is lower in css.
3. concider that this functionality can be achieved without jQuery.

Comment: @MilošMiljković my guy. It was this !important causing the issue. Fixed. Simply just removed important. My mind has been imploding, I've done this at least 10 times in the past and it's worked no issue, this time not! All because I've added an important for no reason!!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: @Joshua Concider approving my answer. Also working example https://codepen.io/miljkovicmisa/pen/QWNLeey